# Clickable icon inside div

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

How to avoid triggering the div click event when clicking on ion-icon

```
<div(click)="goNext()">
    <ion-icon  name="close-circle-outline" size="large" (click)="dissmiss()"></ion-icon>
</div>
```

Comment: A div ist not a button. (And `ion-icon` isn't either) Use the correct element to trigger clicks and handle all states inside the buttons onclick event.

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: you can't add a div in an a button just to detect click event ! html elemens are clickable too

Comment: You should do the following if you want a "correct" html: `<button (click)="..."> </button>` and handle either `goNext()` or `dismiss()` based on state. If you have nested clickable elements then please rethink your structure. This is horrible UX. If you have click events on html elements your page will never be accessible, that's why it's really bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the dissmiss function you have to write your icon code logic. after performing you have to place event.stopPropagation() at the end of dissmiss function to stop event to trigger the parent events.

like this:

```
function dissmiss(event){
  // write code for icon close.
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

the above code runs the logic that you written for icon close and the stopped immediately at this function and will not go to the parent node click.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div(click)="goNext()">
    <ion-icon  name="close-circle-outline" size="large" (click)="dissmiss($event)"></ion-icon>
</div>
```

And in the JS:

```
function dissmiss($event){
    $event.stopPropagation();
}
```